# how to call previous page without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi all i am developing an application for blackberr5 which does not support ajax. By using `window.location.href = "MainMenu.html";` I am navigating from one html into another. Now in MainMenu.html file I have header as :

```
<div data-role="header" align="center">

    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Test.html</h1>
    <a href="MainMenu.html"  data-icon="grid">Menu</a>


</div>
```

But when I click on back it is not going to previous page. And if I use `$.mobile.changePage('MainMenu.html');` then back button works fine. Then for blackberry5 how to handle back button. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Which browser is this on your BlackBerry 5? BTW: So why don't you use `$.mobile.changePage` then since it works? And since you can apparently run javascript, how come that it doesn't support Ajax?

Comment: How to check it? And not only in blackberry5 it is also not working in android2.2 and 4.0 simulator.  changePage support for blackberry6 and above but not in bb5. Therefore I am using window.location

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `history.back()`

You can find some useful info about back buttons in jQuery mobile here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Comment: where to call this history.back()

Comment: use it inside your back button's click event handler

Comment: If I use history.back() still it is not navigating to previous page. If I use window.location.href = "MainMenu.html". But works if I use $.mobile.changePage('MainMenu.html');

Answer (score 2):

try one of these two

history.back() or history.go(-1)

Hope it will work

Comment: with $.mobile.changePage it works but not with window.location.href